# Fastest way to search string in AutoCompleteStringCollection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need help to find the string in `AutoCompleteStringCollection` quickly. I am doing Autocomplete/lookup text in text box. I want to search the particular string when user hit in the text box with `AutoCompleteStringCollection`. I have more records in collection (approx. 100k). If I use a loop, it's taking a long time to get results, so I'd like to get ideas to search the collection fast or copy matched string collection rows quickly. Please find below code taking too much time. This is written in Texbox `TextChanged` event.

```
foreach (String s in textBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource)
{
    if (s.Contains(textBox2.Text))
    {
       listBox1.Items.Add(s);
       listBox1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Please let me know whether I can use any other way to search the string instead `foreach`.

Comment: maybe you should take a look at the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource.aspx) for how to use it

Comment: If you heve a lot of items you can take a look here http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/01/winforms-autocomplete-textbox-using-c.html

Comment: I don't understand your question much. Why do you need search with the use of **AutoCompleteStringCollection** ?

Comment: Hi friends, thanks for your reply. Yes, sorry i did'nt mention that. I am creating my own autocomplete control (due to some limitations found in multiple column show, sorting issue etc.,). for that i am capturing result in autocomplete text box and fetch the string and display into listbox. For this i need quick way of searching. If i achive this i will add other columns in list box (only showing purpose) and colouring etc.. Because i want to enhance more future in my autocomplete and dont want to buy 3rd party controls.Please guid me whether i am going right way or not..

Comment: Thanks WilMaxx and Bastianonm. @ Bastianonm : yes i have tried the same artical, normal .net native autocomplete future little fast only. But i want to show additional columns (like multicombo, list box etc.), so i am thinking new custom control. For this i need to to search string fast way.. please help me.

Comment: You could try implementing the Boyer-Moore algorithm which is supposed to be fast and is used for strings searching, here is a sample: http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/fast-text-search-with-boyer-moore

Comment: @Alexandru-DanMaftei, Thanks a ton for the link.. Yes, correct i am looking fastest way of searching only.I would like to fetch the records from collections. Today i found other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752617/fastest-way-to-search-huge-list-of-big-texts?rq=1 seems high level to me and not able to modify to my requirement. If you have any sample code for search string from collections fastest way, that will be helpful for me.Now i will try this Algorithms and keep you posted. Again Thanks a lot..

Comment: Hi Friend, This sample algoritham method based on full text string based search. I am doing below steps : 1) Connect SQL server and get the item table (Aprx more than 100k records).2) Put all the description (searching field) into one collections. 3) Now when user type some key in text box, i am searching that textbox value into this collections and put matching records into Listbox.Here i am stuck,its taking 15 mins to check the 100 Krecords for each key press. So please help me to give one sample or link to search the strings from collections in fastest way.Please help me out.thanks friend..