# Cascading drop down list Data source

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My team is working on a web application using MVC4 with .NET 4.5. One task is to create a parent drop down list that will update a child drop down list when a value is selected in the parent - for example a drop down list of states would filter a drop down list of cities when a state is selected.

On our other projects we use Ajax calls to a web service or database to populate the values of a child when a parent value is selected. In my example above, the state of Minnesota is selected, and an Ajax call is made to the database to grab all cities in MN. I have read other posts on here and tutorials that follow this concept.

A new developer on our team believe the method above is inefficient and it is better to grab all cities on page load, store the cities as a Jason object in a JavaScript variable and then use jquery to loop through the JavaScript variable and build the child list.

Can someone give me feedback on which method they have used? I don't believe pulling thousands of records into the browser and storing on the client is very efficient when we may only show 10 of the records. This developer also believes looping through a 10000 row JSON object in JavaScript is faster than making a database call to grab 10 rows.

Comment: I lean more towards *not* bringing so much wasted data to the client. A desktop browser will probably handle it smoothly, but it's wasted bandwidth if nothing else. For slowly-changing data like cities, you can heavily leverage caching and eliminate database traffic.

Comment: I agree with OP and with `Tim medora`, if you dont have to get all the data by one iteration you dont need to push 10000 rows to JSON. It will be uneffective. BUT if you anyway get the whole 10000 rows by AJAX request, pushing data to the browser will be more effective.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I would like to cache the data and reduce the number of database calls. I think this would be a good compromise. I really don't believe storing 100s or 1000s of JSON objects in a js variable is needed

Comment: Even without explicit caching, the database will add its own caching/optimization to the mix and it's still my preferred method. *With* caching, it should be blazing fast; a single AJAX request to pull just the cities you need. If you want to support searching (e.g. for autocomplete), you can build and store a data structure like a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) containing all cities in the server's cache.

Comment: @TimMedora I've never implemented a true before and I will look into this. Would a dictionary be somewhat similar? The dictionary would contain a key of each state and a list of cities as the value?

Comment: 1) A dictionary with the state name/ID as the key will work great if you just want to grab the cities in a state (as your original question states). 2) A trie can be dictionary-based, but is a little more elaborate. *You may not need/want a trie*. I mentioned it because it's an efficient structure which can make real-time searching feasible if that's something you do want (or if some developer tries to claim it can only be done by downloading all the data first). I discuss it more in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8623535/453277

Comment: @Maris for our requirements we will not make any Ajax call to grab all 10000 rows. In our case the user must select a specific state and then the cities will be built. The 10000 rows example I used is a sum of all the cities in all the states, which will never be returned in one AJAX call

Comment: Then you definetly have to use the AJAX requests instead of pulling all cities to javascript in JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your list and you can call everything from LINQ. Check the cache to create from there before you do your other calls to instantiate

```
public IList<Example> GetList(string _state)
{

    IList<Example> cities = new List<Example>();

    Cache cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;

    if (cache[_state] != null)
        cities = (IList<Example>)cache[_state];

    else
    {
        //Do your calls
        cache.Insert(_state, cities);
    }

    return cities;
}
```